Is it important that a title is phrased as a question?
Many questions don't have their titles phrased as a question. Some examples:

Strange transaction (block 71036)
Best GPUs for Mining
Business-grade Bitcoind implementation
Push notification of incoming transaction

I'm tempted to edit them but I thought that I should check what the community thinks first. Is it important? Should the title always be a question or are there exceptions?

Related question on MSO: How can we get more people to make their title a question?

It's far more important that the title clearly explain what the question is and, together with the tags, allow a person to determine if they're likely to be able to answer the question. Putting the title in the form of a question helps to ensure that, but if you can do it another way, there's nothing wrong with that.
Your first example shows, I think, the opposite of your point: "Strange transaction (block 71036)". The most obvious ways to turn this into a question make it worse: "What is the deal with the strange transaction in block 71036?"
Yes, you can come up with better ways to put it in the form of a question. But that's basically because you can always come up with a better title. I'll bet I can take the first five titles that are in the form of a question and come up with better titles that aren't in that form.
So it's a good guideline because it makes sure you don't forget to ask a question and it does help to make the list of questions look better. But slavish devotion to it is not a good idea.

Good point, I agree completely.

You should feel free to do any edit that you think improves a question. If a title is better as a question, edit it - the op shouldn't mind.
